# Complex eigenvalue general solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I solved for a general solution of the DE,

y''+2y'+2y=0

Where the answer is

y=C$e^{-t}$cost+C$e^{-t}$sint        ,     where C are different constants

Then I also solved for the general solultion, by turning it into a matrix, and using complex eigenvalues.
I get the gen solultion
y=C$e^{-t}$${cost-sint \choose 2cost}$+C$e^{-t}$${cost+sint \choose sint}$

So my question is this: I understand I am using different methods in each way, but since I am solving for a general solution of the same DE, why dont the general solutions look the same? Or are they the same, but maybe I dont see how they are the same?

Thank you

Comment: ${cost+sint \choose sint}$? What does that even mean?

Comment: @IvanNeretin It is what you get where you split up the real and imaginary parts, refer to this: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/system/linear/eigenvalue/complex/complex.html

Comment: OK, I got that. See, what does it mean to "turn your equation into a matrix"? You had **one** DE, and its answer was (supposedly) one function. Now you have a system of **two** DEs, and it has two unknown functions. You can't compare two functions to one. How are they related?

Comment: But shouldn't they be comparable somehow? Shouldn't they be very similar since you are looking for the same thing in the same DE.

Comment: How can **one function** be similar to **two functions**? Yes, they are related, but _how_? What steps did you take to get from a second-order DE to that matrix thing?

Comment: I dont know, a derivative?

Comment: OK, what's with that derivative?

Comment: a constant? Im not familiar enough with all this stuff to see the relationships...

Comment: You shouldn't use the same $y$ to denote two different things. The first one, namely the second order linear differential equation, you called $y$. To convert a second order system to a system of first order system, you probably want to do something similar to that link you posted.

Comment: okay, but what about the similarities